# Angular 2 Observables: Secure way to get the value that return my service

Tags: angular

I am looking for ways to treat the results that this observable throws at me and that I can always get the values that the service returns to me from outside the callback.

A problem that I am presenting:

It often happens that, although the service returns the value to me successfully, I am not able to save the information successfully in `this.templateFields[key].Lookup`

```
  private getLookUpsFromFields() {
  var lu: any[] = [];
  //console.log('templatefields', this.templateFields);
  for (const key in this.templateFields) {
  if (this.templateFields[key].SimpleDataType === 'String List, Multi' ||
      this.templateFields[key].SimpleDataType === 'String List, Single') {
    //console.log('Field Lookup', this.templateFields[key].Field);
    this._lookUpsService.getLookUpsOfField(this.model, this.templateFields[key].Field).subscribe(success => {
       lu = this._lookUpsService.getArrayLook(success['metadataAllLookUpField']);
         localStorage.setItem(this.templateFields[key].Field, JSON.stringify(lu));
         }, error => {
            this.ShowMsg(error);
      });
      this.templateFields[key].Lookups =   JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.templateFields[key].Field));
    }
    //localStorage.removeItem(this.templateFields[key].Field);
  }
}
```

//lookupsservice

```
getLookUpsOfField(model: string, field: string){
  //console.log(this.url + '/' + model + '/' + propertyType);
return this._httpS.get(this.url + '/' + model + '/' + field);
}


getArrayLook(lookups: any) {
  var array: any[] = [];
  if (lookups !== undefined && lookups !== null) {
    lookups.map(x => {
      array.push({Field: x.lookup_values.split(x.delimiter)[0], value: x.lookup_values.split(x.delimiter)[1]});
  });
  }
  return array;
}
```

I know one way to treat the returned values of the service is to deal with them within the scope of the observable, but what other alternatives do I have? Apart from these 2 alternatives I show:
1-) Using LocalStorage
2-) Treating the logic inside the scope of the observable

I want to guarantee that **this.templateFields[key].Lookup** always receives the returned value of the callback.

Some alternative?
Any extra information will be provided.
I'm working with angular 2+

Answer (score 0):

you can create service to store data and get data 
create one variable to store data
create to methods to set data and get data

//data service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class CommonDataService {
 public Data:any;

    getData(): any{
            return this.Data;
        }

        setData(data: any) {
            this.Data= data;
        }
}
```

when you want to store data call set method of service and when want to get data then call get method of service

```
private getLookUpsFromFields() {
  var lu: any[] = [];
  //console.log('templatefields', this.templateFields);
  for (const key in this.templateFields) {
  if (this.templateFields[key].SimpleDataType === 'String List, Multi' ||
      this.templateFields[key].SimpleDataType === 'String List, Single') {
    //console.log('Field Lookup', this.templateFields[key].Field);
    this._lookUpsService.getLookUpsOfField(this.model, this.templateFields[key].Field).subscribe(success => {
       lu = this._lookUpsService.getArrayLook(success['metadataAllLookUpField']);
         this._commonDataService.setData(JSON.stringify(lu));
         }, error => {
            this.ShowMsg(error);
      });
      this.templateFields[key].Lookups =   JSON.parse(this._commonDataService.getData()));
    }
    //localStorage.removeItem(this.templateFields[key].Field);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, that posible solution didn't work for me, right now I'm fiding another way, i thinking again if this way to call the lookups is correct or not.